# Adpapt Drawer Menu React Native

Tags: react-native, routes, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

Im using a Drawer Menu on my application from github, but I want to make Routes an organize it, to connect the menu to other pages, etc... I dont know how can I do that..

```
const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState("Home");
  // To get the curretn Status of menu ...
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);

  // Animated Properties...

  const offsetValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  // Scale Intially must be One...
  const scaleValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const closeButtonOffset = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start', padding: 15 }}>
        <Image source={profile} style={{
          width: 60,
          height: 60,
          borderRadius: 10,
          marginTop: 8
        }}></Image>

        <Text style={{
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: 'white',
          marginTop: 20
        }}>Daniel Filipe</Text>

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={{
            marginTop: 6,
            color: 'white'
          }}>View Profile</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, marginTop: 50 }}>
          {
            // Tab Bar Buttons....
          }

          {TabButton(currentTab, setCurrentTab, "Home", home)}
          {TabButton(currentTab, setCurrentTab, "Search", search)}
          {TabButton(currentTab, setCurrentTab, "Notifications", notifications)}
          {TabButton(currentTab, setCurrentTab, "Settings", settings)}

        </View>
          
        <View>
          {TabButton(currentTab, setCurrentTab, "LogOut", logout)}
        </View>

      </View>
```

I never used TabButtons and I dont know how can I adapt this for my personal use..

Comment: Your current code doesn't even have a drawer?

Comment: I thought that code was enought because the navigation is in the "TabButtons"..

Comment: Recommend: try [Drawer Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator) to build your Drawer, or [Bottom Tab Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator) to build Bottom Tab